# Redux usecase in react native application

Tags: android, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am learning [redux](http://redux.js.org/) to implement in my `react-native` android application. I see it helps to maintain state in an application.

For instance if user has logged then it helps to save user state to logged to true kinda. I hope I took correct example. I see `react-native` has `AsyncStorage` also where we can save this also whether user has logged or not.

We can write a logic if user has logged then set logged to true in `AsyncStorage` and false on log out. Now, check on splash screen whether this is true or false then navigate accordingly.

This is a bit confusion now if this state can be managed using `AsyncStorage` then what is the use case of `redux` in `react-native` application. Can anyone explain by taking an example ?

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncStorage` is for react-native what `localStorage` is for browsers, but it is async.

I assume you use JWT for authentication, you can use `AsyncStorage` to store the token.

```
// on login 
AsyncStorage.setItem('@token', value)
```

In your entry screen of the application, you can get the token from the `AsyncStorage`, and based on the decoded value of the token you can update the store and make redirects.

```
// componentWillMount
AsyncStorage.getItem('@token')
  .then(token => {

    const decodedToken = decodeToken(token)

    if (isExpired(decodeToken)) // redirect to login

    // save the values to the store
    someAction(decodedToken)

  })
```

Anyway, if you use redux in your application, no matter the framework, everything related to your application state should be handled by redux.

In conclusion, you should `AsyncStorage` to store tokens but not state like `isConnected, isLoggedIn, user`...

Comment: In Android, If you see we use `SharedPreference` which is much similar to `AsyncStorage`, things work well.

Comment: BTW when redux clear store ? on uninstalling app or closing app ?

Comment: when the application is closed, but the AsyncStorage persist, unless you clear the data (under Application -> Your App -> Clear data) or uninstall.

Comment: Alright. IMO This is likely very less usecase of it in react-native. Not sure I am correct.

Comment: Well, I don't think you are right, using redux in react-native it is the same as using in a react project, storing the application state in the same place I think it's a lot better than having multiple components that use setState() but depends on the project and preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Storing credentials(or important/crucial information) in `AsyncStorage` is not really safe. It can be accessed if you know where to look :)

I too was working on `react-native` application. I store the encrypted token in `AsyncStorage`. When the user logs in I get that token and call server(login api) and get the `accessToken` (validation is taken care by server). I need to pass this `accessToken` in all API calls. I use combination of `axios` and `apollo` so I store this `accessToken` in my redux store once logged in and read it from there.

I also use redux at few more places:-

1. Opening/Closing keyboard at few places
2. Redirecting to login page in case token is expired

Hope it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe Redux (and all other frameworks) have a value when you are developing in teams, since the developers can have common design across the products they are developing, greatly reducing the onboarding period of a new colleague.

For the technical part, in case of small codebase I don't recommend Redux, since it will only cause you headaches, and you will end up wondering why do you even need these boilerplates.

On the other hand, when the product is growing continuously, Redux allows you to scale the codebase with less complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than dealing with AsyncStorage yourself, look into [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist). This way you deal state with redux as it is and redux-persit will handle storing and retrieving of the token from AsyncStorage for you.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing this 3 steps in your applications, it will load and save your state automatically with AsyncStorage and you will be able to access it on any Component you wish.

1) Setup [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) to load/save automagically the state

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { persistStore, autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist'; 

import { yourReducers } from './reducers'; 

const store = compose(
   autoRehydrate()
)(createStore)(yourReducers);
```

2) On your main/index component setup storage method to AsyncStorage and wait for the state to be loaded before rendering your application

```
export default class index extends Component { 
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { rehydrated: false };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        persistStore(store, {storage: AsyncStorage}, () => {
        this.setState({rehydrated: true});
        });
    }

   render() { 
    if(!this.state.rehydrated)
        return <View />;
    else
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
               <YourLoginScreen-or-Router />
            </Provider>
        );}
}
```

3) This allows your LoginScreen to access the state and send your user to the next screen if the state contains an user, i recommend using a router to do this

```
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class LoginScreen extends Component {
    ...

    componentWillMount() {
        if (this.props.user !== null)
            Actions.ShowScreenWhereUserIsLoggedIn(); //If you dont use react-native-router-flux change to your navigator
    }

    render() {
        ....        
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ auth }) => {
    const { user } = auth;

    return { user };
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,{}
)(LoginScreen);
```

`auth` is your login/session reducer which will save your `user` when it is logged in and call the router/navigator to switch screen

You can read more about redux here: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/

Comment: I think we can do same with state, then how redux is different than normal state ?